# help on jQuery working trying to autoFocus on the next input field after keyUp, being as generic as possible

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

the HTML

```
<input class="fr pinPass" type="password" name="pin1" id="pin1_1" tabindex="100"/>
<label>Enter the third number</label>

<br class="cb"/>

<input class="fr pinPass" type="password" name="pin1" id="pin1_2" tabindex="101"/>
<label>Enter the fourth number</label>                                      
<br class="cb"/>

<input class="fr pinPass" type="password" name="pin1" id="pin1_3" tabindex="102"/>  
<label>Enter the second number</label>
```

the current jQuery

```
$(".pinPass").focus(function () {
    $(this).keyup(function(){
         $("input").siblings('.pinPass').filter(':first').focus();              
    });
});
```

the Problem:

I am trying to set autoFocus on the next input field after keyUp in each input field.
So far I;ve come up with solution that keep looping thru until it gets to the last one being selected, or if I use the :first filter, it always return to the first one it finds on the page.

I don't think I can use next(), as it's not the next node in the set. 
There will always be labels separating each input field.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: have you even tried next? there shouldbe any problem as long as it's only the input that has the specified selector .pinPass

Comment: correct me if im wrong but i tought elements with the same name should be added as an aray like this `name="pin1[]"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/), but [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) will only return the *very* next siblings *if* it matches the selector.  Instead you want [`.nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) with a selector, like this:

```
$(".pinPass").keyup(function(){
  $(this).nextAll('.pinPass:first').focus();
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/GpsEy/).

Comment: Magic. I only just read about nextAll a couple minutes ago!  I knew next() wouldn't work, and was having loop problems with nextAll - but a combination of nextAll and the first filter works a treat. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Next can have selectors aswell.

```
$(this).next('input');
```